# Equal sign in Boost RegEx

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I've got a problem with the following Boost regular expression,

```
boost::regex e("=");
if(regex_search("=", e)) cout << "yeah";
```

Can anybody please tell me why I don't get a "yeah"?
This is Boost 1.37 with Visual Studio 2008.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using that same code, I *do* get the "yeah" here.

Note that I had to add `boost::` to the beginning of `regex_search`, and that I'm running on GCC under Linux. I don't have Boost 1.37 set up under Windows yet, so I can't easily test it there.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the code you gave, on Visual Studio 2008, with Boost 1.37, and it compiles, runs, and outputs "yeah". Are you sure you set up Boost correctly?

Comment: Yup. Works for me, too, and I have the same setup.